# Paypal donation in android application

Tags: android, paypal

I know several topics have come across about this subject, but I'd like to be sure and know what is allowed once and for all.

I'm planning on releasing an app in the android market for free. I'd like to add a donate button in the menu which links to my paypal donate link. Donating will not cause any changes to the app like adding extra functionality.

Is this allowed?

I've read it is on several pages, claiming that you can do this as long as you don't add extra functionalities or other things to the app. Others say you just can't get around the 30% fee.

I wan't to release my app on the official android market so releasing it by myself or on another market is no option.

Thank you

Comment: There are peaople saying to do it in that link, but is it allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Koush has a pretty slick open sourced library that you would probably find useful.

[ClockworkModBillingLibrary](https://github.com/koush/ClockworkModBillingLibrary)

Comment: I already have a way of implementing the payment, I'd like to know whether or not it is legal to do it. Thank you for the link anyway, mayby this implementation is better. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: To answer you question, I had only read the title before, yes it's legal. You can definitely add a donate link within your app to PayPal. Just make sure people know they are donating to YOU and not an organization, charity, or whatever.

Comment: I did some Google searches for ["legality of paypal donations"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=Nel3TtmVHoWy8QOvxYiMDQ&ved=0CBoQvwUoAQ&q=legality+of+paypal+donations&spell=1&biw=1366&bih=653) That and [PayPal kind of promotes it.](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/use-cases/android-app)

Comment: ClockworkModBillingLibrary link is dead, and i had no lunk in searching in google... any clue?

Comment: @FrancescoR I guess Koush removed the repo.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently google doesn’t like paypal donation buttons:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/dZ2z6Hg9w_E

Answer (score 2):

You can have a donation button:
I use this for my donation buttons and have it set as a picture button:

```
`Donate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/your_paypal"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });`
```

to get the link version click the email version when setting up the button.
if the donations are for you i would name the button "support the devs"